# Laravel 5 - site doesnt show anything

Tags: laravel, middleware

I created a new middleware for https only and uploaded it on my cpanel and defined it to my kernel.after that the site has not shown anything
i did config:cache and composer dump-autoload and reupload vendor/composer but nothing changed
anyone can help?

Comment: Can you share the said middleware?

Comment: i deleted it and chenged my kernel

Comment: `class HttpsProtocol {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
            if (!$request->secure() && App::environment() === 'production') {
                return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
            }

            return $next($request); 
    }
}`

Comment: I don' t think this is the right way to handle the ` http://` redirect to `https://` try to look solution on server end like implementing it on .htaccess or directly on your virtual host. Otherwise you might suffer from 'Too many redirect" error thrown by browser